# Is it possible to add a sleep() method in a print statement in Java?

Tags: java

I am working on a basic addition game in Eclipse, and at the end, I have the program display the total number of points the user earned throughout it.

I want it to have a slight delay `DURING the print statement` before printing the actual value of the total points variable. I want to do something like this:

```
//Prints final number of points after three seconds
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long) 3);

System.out.println("\nYour total number of points is... "    
+ TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long) 3) + NumberOfPoints + ".");

//I want to print NumberOfPoints on the same line as the first print statement.
```

I know it's not the best way to write this, but I am still fairly new to Java. Any answers may help me in formatting my future questions. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just separate to 2 print statements (without using "println" which inserts a new line) and have the sleep between them?

Comment: Having, `thread.sleep()` would be the easiest way to do that. Just have it between your print statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different functions worth understanding here: `System.out.println()` and `System.out.print()`. The first inserts a line break at the end of the string you pass to it, but the second does not.

That means you can do this:

```
System.out.print("Your total number of points is... wait for it... ");
Thread.sleep(3, SECONDS)
System.out.print(numberOfPoints + " points!");
```

And both print statements will appear on the same line.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I've been trying to figure this simple thing out for 20 minutes now.

Comment: Happy to help. You could consider printing a "." three times with a second delay between each to let the user know something is happening (and build dramatic tension!)

Comment: I was thinking about doing that. Couldn't decide. Just for fun I will.